# How do I make a dictionary of OD pairs from a distance Matrix using python?

Tags: python, dictionary, matrix, distance, od

I have a flow matrix from an excel workbook that shows me the movement of cargo between 2 points similar to this:

---

```
  1 2 3 ... n
1 0 7 8    
2 5 0 3     .
3 6 9 0     .
.        .  .
.  ...    .
.          .
n           0
```

---

I'm trying to create a dictionary where each key consists of each Origin-Destination pair like this:

```
{(1,1):0; 
 (1,2):7; 
 (1,3):8; 
  ...; 
 (3,2):9; 
 (3,3):0;
  ...;
 (n-1,n-1): x
 (n,n): 0}
```

Any ideas & help will be highly appreciated!!

What i've done so far is:

```
import pandas as pd

#Data Commodities#
Kdata= pd.read_excel('turquia.xls', sheet_name = 'Flow')
K = {}
for i in Kdata:
    for j in Kdata:
      K.update({(i,j):Kdata[i]})
```

I'm getting a dictionary that has the OD pairs but it's inserting all distances in every element:

`

```
Name: 12, Length: 81, dtype: float64,
 (12,13): 
 0     7115.284948
 1     2356.131379
 2     3077.130525
 3     1994.241678
 4     1374.186546
 ...   
 76     632.489214
 77     845.193097
 78     430.053121
 79    1728.571316
 80    1181.537133
```

`

Comment: post the code you have tried

Comment: `
import pandas as pd

#Data Commodities#
Kdata= pd.read_excel('turquia.xls', sheet_name = 'Flow')
K = {}
for i in Kdata:
    for j in Kdata:
      K.update({(i,j):Kdata[i]})`

I'm getting a dictionary that has the OD pairs but it's inserting all distances in every element:

`
Name: 12, Length: 81, dtype: float64,
 (12,13): 
 0     7115.284948
 1     2356.131379
 2     3077.130525
 3     1994.241678
 4     1374.186546
 ...   
 76     632.489214
 77     845.193097
 78     430.053121
 79    1728.571316
 80    1181.537133
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a straight forward `unstack()` `to_dict()` in `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd
import io
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""id  1 2 3 
1 0 7 8    
2 5 0 3
3 6 9 0"""), sep="\s+").set_index("id")

df.unstack().to_dict()
```

**output**

```
{('1', 1): 0,
 ('1', 2): 5,
 ('1', 3): 6,
 ('2', 1): 7,
 ('2', 2): 0,
 ('2', 3): 9,
 ('3', 1): 8,
 ('3', 2): 3,
 ('3', 3): 0}
```

Comment: your output is wrong `(1, 2) -> 7` and `(2, 1) -> 5`

Comment: if you want it to be row major,  just transpose first `df.T.unstack().to_dict()`

Comment: Gonna try it and see what happens